# Android turning clicks into touches

Tags: android

I have an on click listener:

```
whiteKeyPressedArray[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {
}}
```

I see that this allows touches:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

//Switch case for type of touch
}
```

But how can I detect touch rather than click on my whiteKeyPressedArray[i]?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the whiteKeyPressedArray[i] is, but have you tried:

```
whiteKeyPressedArray[i].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true; // or false if you want the event to pass on
    }
});
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Via the MotionEvent you can fetch the action like ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP, ACTION_MOVE, etc. So it is propably more powerful than onClick

Comment: The return type is incompatible with View.OnTouchListener.onTouch(View, MotionEvent)

Comment: Yes, this was my fault sorry. The return type of onTouch is boolean. Returning false allows the event to bubble along, being handles by another view. Returning true stops the event chain, making your onTouch method the only one reacting to the event - I update my answer and correct the return type

Answer (score 1):

OnTouch will fire many many times :), actually onTouch will be trigered over and over again as long as you keep your finger to that element (as long as you touch that element). Where onClick will be fire just ones but ONLY if you return false from your onTouch handler.

Comment: Just to add.  You use onTouch for touch events like finger moves and whatnot.  You use onClick for a "select" action (finger down then up in the same view).  You can use onTouch for the same purpose, but it takes a little more work.